# Prevent column wrapping in unordered list, align list items to top of column

Tags: css, alignment, listitem, word-wrap, css-multicolumn-layout

I have an unordered list that contains several list items, split into 4 columns - Image below.

[image: Unordered list, containing list-items that each contain an image, an h2 element, and separate unordered lists and list-items underneath.]

I'm having trouble getting the list-items at the upper level - The ones that have the images next to them in the image example - to break the column and start at the next column if they would otherwise overlap.

I've tried setting CSS attributes on each of the UL elements throughout the CSS, such as:

```
-webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
-moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
-webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
-o-column-break-inside:avoid;
```

However, nothing seems to change. I thought this was the style that would control this, but I must be wrong.

**What I'm asking, specifically, is how I can prevent the contents of a list-item from wrapping to the next column in an unordered list.**

Comment: post a snippet with enough html and css that the issue is replicated in your post. see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: I'll work on getting an HTML example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized while attempting to create a sample for review, that the issue was only occurring for me in Internet Explorer.

Adding the style **'break-inside:avoid;'** corrected the problem in that browser; it appeared the issue was not present in the browsers that were covered by the other styles.

Comment: I believe that most the time when you attempt to isolate your problem you will end up solving it in the process.

Comment: In this case, I actually wasn't able to fully isolate / re-create the problem. The HTML was a page being procedurally / automatically generated from a 3rd party app; I only have access to configure the CSS being used. Most of the html content gets loaded as a result of a java-script call that only works if you're authenticated, so I couldn't find a way to export the HTML without it just being a mostly blank page, lol. It wasn't until I looked at a separate copy of the app on a different server that I realized it worked in Opera, a separate browser, and made the connection.